# Cannot drop a function in Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

For some reason, I cannot drop a function in Redshift via TablePlus.

The function clearly exists which I can see in the UI, I tried both:

- manually right clicking the delete on that function
- `DROP FUNCTION "SCHEMA".sp_migrate_test();` (directly from copy SCRIPT AS DROP)

I am on the admin account, and upon exiting/ re-entering the procedure is still there. Is there anything which I missed?

[image]

[image]

Same thing happens if I create an entirely new procedure, and try to drop it in literally the following line.

Comment: Was the DROP COMMITted?

Comment: Does the function take parameters? If so, you'd need to use something like `drop function sp_migrate_test(int)`

Comment: @BillWeiner Yes it was committed, I get the same error as if running the SQL DROP FUNCTION statement.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It does, although I just tried passing strings, data types, or even copying the exact line from the CREATE script. Still throwing a function doesn't exist error....

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Just re-created the functions without any parameters, still the same error, so strange

Comment: Try a different SQL client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out TablePlus suggested this as `DROP FUNCTION`, instead of `DROP PROCEDURE`

So couldn't drop it using the GUI, however using `DROP FUNCTION PROCEDURE_NAME(PARAMETERS)` worked fine, as @John Rotenstein mentioned, have to pass these in for it to work.